# how to call methods inside the constructor in a calss

Tags: javascript, class

Hello I am trying to solve an exercise where we have to create a class Appliance and then two child classes (tv and washing machine), then I need to check the color and the consumption of the appliance, or their childs, and if none is passed it will be given a default value with a method. So far this is what I have but it keeps telling me this.checkcolor is not a function; I have tried the syntax also like `this.color = checkColor(color)` and also with constant giving the default values but nothing seems to work.
What would it be the easiest way to do this? Thanks

````js
function Appliance(color, consumption, weight){     

    this.color = this.checkColor(color);
    this.consumption =  this.checkConsumption(consumption);
    this.weight = weight || 5;  
    this.price = this.getPrice(this.consumption, this.weight);

    Appliance.prototype.checkConsumption = function(consumption){
        let res = "";
        const consumptions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
        for(let i = 0; i < consumptions; i++){
            if(consumptions[i] == consumption){
                res = consumption;
            }
            else{
                res = "F";
            }
        }
        return res
    }       

    Appliance.prototype.checkColor = function(color){
        let res = "";       
        let checker = false;
        const colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "grey"];
        for(let i = 0; i < colors.length && !checker; i++){
            if(colors[i] == color){
                checker = true;
            }           
        }

        if(checker){
            res = color;
        }
        else{
            res = "white";
        }   
        return res;
    }

    Appliance.prototype.getPrice = function(consumption, weight){
        let defaultPrice = 100;
        let extra = 0;
        switch(consumption){
            case "A":
            extra += 100;
            break;
            case "B":
            extra += 80;
            break;
            case "C":
            extra += 60;
            break;
            case "D":
            extra += 50;
            break;
            case "E":
            extra += 30;
            break;
            case "F":
            extra += 10;
            break;
        }

        if(weight >= 0 && weight < 19){
            extra += 10;
        }else if(weight >= 20 && weight < 49){
            extra += 50;
        }else if(weight >= 50 && weight <= 79){
            extra += 80;
        }else if(weight >= 80){
            extra += 100;
        }

        return defaultPrice + extra;
    }   

    Appliance.prototype.getColor = function(){
        return this.color;      
    }

    Appliance.prototype.getConsumption = function(){
        return this.consumption;
    }

    Appliance.prototype.getWeight = function(){
        return this.weight;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: The code is adding prototype methods to `Appliance.prototype` inside the constructor after a call to `checkColor` has already been attempted Add methods to `Appliance.prototype` outside the constructor before calling it the first time.

Comment: thaks a lot for your comments I sorted it out and I understood better how it works. Thanks!!!